# What are keychain-access-groups?

Tags: ios, keychain

On Apple Keychain reference documentation, it reads that a keychain access group is a identifier that the app may share items with.  What does this mean exactly?  Does this mean that an app can share keychain credentials with a different app on the same device?

Comment: Yes, but all of the apps must be from the same developer. You can also use it to share keychain items between your main app and extensions.

Comment: How about between two main apps?

Comment: Yes as long as they are signed by the same developer